# Почему не работает composer?

Tags: ubuntu, composer

**Ubuntu**
Когда захожу c **Google Chrome** на сайт **Composer** , то получаю ошибку *Не удается получить доступ к сайту ( внизу ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT )*
Когда в терминале запускаю команду, например **composer self-update**, то получаю ошибку 
*[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out*

Когда пробую запустить **composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"** , то получаю ошибку
*The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date*

Но в браузере **FireFox** на сайт composer заходит. 
Файл hosts стандартный, прокси нету.

**Windows**
Загружаюсь с данного пк под Windows, та же ситуация, только с firefox не пробовал.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалась проблема с интернетом.